# How to check if textbox is entered to allow user to select radio button javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make sure user inputs text in the text field before being able to select the radio button. If the gateway field is blank, do alert the user that they haven't inputted anything in the field and return.

This is what I have so far:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="gatewayInput">
     <form>
             <input type="text" name="gateway" placeholder="Gateway Name"><br><br>
            </form>
    </div>

<div class="box1">
  <form method="post" action="javascript:alert('Success')"  onsubmit="validate()">
<label class="col">Air/Ground</label>
<span class="col">
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
  <label for="r1">Air</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
  <label for="r2">Ground</label>
 </span>
  <span class="col">
   <input type="submit" class="button"/>
   </span>
  </form>
</div>
<script src ="../../../jqueryDir/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
     if ((document.getElementsByName("gateway")[0].value == '')) {
  alert('Response required');
  return false;
 }
            else {
  alert('Sucess');
  return true;
 }
}
console.log("this is my value:" + document.getElementsByName("gateway")[0].value);
    $(".button").click(function(event){
            if ( validate() == true ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                            url:"testexec.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {option: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val()},
                            dataType: "text",
                            success:function(result){
                            $('#div1').html(result)

                            }
                    });
            }
       });

</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
```

I dont think this part is working, it doesnt seem to be calling my validate function:

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:alert('Success')"  onsubmit="validate()">
```

Also i am checking onsubmit, is there a way to alert the user before this? Like right when they click the radio button, alert them with the message?

Answer (score 0):

And `validate(e) {` to the function declaration and `e.preventDefault();` to the beginning of the function to prevent the form from submitting before running your code.

```
function validate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ((document.getElementsByName("gateway")[0].value == '')) {
        alert('Response required');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Sucess');
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that didnt work. I still didn't get a pop up alert with empty text field

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit="validate()"` is duplicated with `$(".button").click(function(event)`.
You can merge them together:

```
$(".button").click(function(event){
  validate();
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Since you have `event.preventDefault()`, no need `action` or `onsubmit` on form.

```
<form method="post">
```

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work, but after the alert box pops up it still runs the ajax after that and still outputs to the screen. If I return shouldn't it exit out of the function?

Comment: nevermind I figured it out. I need to check before the execution. updated code above.